# Gulp zip missing some files in a folder

Tags: gulp, gulp-zip

I want to create zip of all the files and folders inside the /dist folder.

I have folder structure like :

```
/dist 
    /audio/
    /css/
    /icons/
    /js/
    /libs/
    /locales/en-US
    /locales/mr
    /locales/hi
    /locales/te
    /locales/fr
```

I basically want to use **gulp-zip** to zip up my entire /dist folder and sub-folders and save the zip inside it. So this is what i am doing :

```
var bases = {
    app: 'app/',
    dist: 'dist/',
};    
gulp.task('zip', function () {
        return gulp.src(bases.dist + '**')
            .pipe(using())
            .pipe(zip('buildTest.zip'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./' + bases.dist));
    });
```

with this i am able to create buildTest.zip but it don't include all the sub-folders from /locales.Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gulp runs dependency tasks in asynchronous fashion as much as possible, so instead of using zip as dependency task, make zip task to depend on build task and have the default task run the zip task, as follow

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const zip = require('gulp-zip');

gulp.task('build', ['copyAssets', 'minify-js', 'minify-css']);

gulp.task('zip', ['build'], function() {
    gulp.src('dist/**')
        .pipe(zip('archive.zip'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
  gulp.start('zip');
});
```

Comment: I'm using the same approach but I still have files missing, although not at every run.

Comment: @KeesdeBruin : I did some work around for this issue which is working fine for me. I added **gulp.start('zip');** task in setTimeout function.
    setTimeout(function () {
        gulp.start('zip');
    }, 3000);

Comment: A bit late but I've managed to reorder and split some of the tasks and now it behaves as it should without using `gulp.start`